# Replace quotation marks in sql query in perl script

Tags: mysql, sql, perl, dbi

I have a text file of data that I am importing into a MySQL database. Some of the lines unfortunatley contain quotation marks, which causes my SQL queries to go haywire. I would like to get rid of any field that has quotation marks, or at very least ignore them in my query.

I found something that might work, but being as this is run through a Perl script I am having issues "escaping" the quotation marks. I really don't know how and can't figure it out. I would like to just search through my table and delete any quotation marks (") that it may find or replace it with a single quotation mark or space or anything really.

```
my $myreplacequery = "REPLACE(s.Title, '"','')";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($myreplacequery);
$sth->execute;
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please edit `my $replacequery` to `$myreplacequery`?

Comment: Can you post a code sample which is going "haywire"?

Comment: I can't get this to work, so I decided to just use perl to find/replace quotes in the file that I am inputting into the tables originally before it even gets to SQL. Hopefully this will work, can't tell yet.

Answer (score 1):

Perl has `q` and `qq` ([quote-like operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators)) for this kind of situation. They allow you to choose the quote character to use. `q` acts like a single-quote (`'`) and doesn't interpolate (expand variables) while `qq` acts like a double quote (`"`) and does.

```
my $replacequery = q{REPLACE(s.Title, '"','')};
```

Answer (score 1):

Change query to UPDATE on this table:

```
 update tablename set title = REPLACE(title,'\"','\'') where title like '%\"%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually want to pass a string consisting of a single quote to `REPLACE` for its 3rd arg, but you're passing an empty string. The necessary SQL is:

```
REPLACE(s.Title, '"', '\'')
```

To create that string in Perl, you could use either of the following string literals:

```
"REPLACE(s.Title, '\"', '\\'')"    # Produces: REPLACE(s.Title, '"', '\'')

qq{REPLACE(s.Title, '"', '\\'')}   # Produces: REPLACE(s.Title, '"', '\'')
```

Notice how `"` needed to be escaped. Without it, Perl would see the following string literal (followed by junk):

```
"REPLACE(s.Title, '"
^                  ^
|                  |
start              end
of string          of string
literal            literal
```